# Update ProgressDialog with ProgressBar after rotation

Tags: java, android, progressdialog, android-thread

My application processes some images in a thread and meanwhile it shows a dialog with a progressbar.

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Activity.this);
progressDialog.setProgressStyle(size);
progressDialog.show();
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++{
            //process images
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progressDialog.setProgress(i);
                }
            });
        }

    }
});
thread.start();
```

Now, if a rotation occurs I do

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    super.onDestroy();
}
```

and in `onCreate` I recreate the dialog. But the thread don't changes the progressbar of this new dialog.

Answer (score 1):

After rotation the Activity (or the Fragment) in which this dialog is shown is discarded and a new one is created.

You re-create the dialog in the new Activity, but the thread you started updates the dialog in the old one (the fact that this thread has a reference to the old dialog also constitutes a memory leak).

I'd suggest that you do the following:

1. Implement some ImageProcessor class and put an instance of it in Application object.
2. Make ImageProcessor class observable and notify the listeners about the progress.
3. Get a reference to this object in Activity and subscribe to notifications in onStart() (and unsubscribe in onStop()).
4. When status update notifications arrive - update the progress indication

Using this approach you'll have the processing logic encapsulate in a special object that survives rotation, and different components can invoke its methods and subscribe to notifications from it.

Comment: I am not really into this and I never worked with the Application object. How I keep the ImageProcessor class and subscribe to notifications after the device was rotated?

Comment: @Vasiliy, Explaing with an example code will make everything clear.